# Set no transition with navigateTo NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

I would like to know how can I set no transition with NativeScript.

Currently, I have this :

```
this.$navigateTo(LogIn, {
    frame: "app",
    clearHistory: false,
})
```

I would like to show directly LogIn frame without transition. I tried with this, with set **duration 0**, or set **transition : false**, but I have always transition :

```
this.$navigateTo(LogIn, {
    frame: "app",
    clearHistory: false,
    transition: {
      name: "fade",
      duration: 0,
      curve: "easeIn"
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `transition` to `false`, try setting `animated` to `false`. Below is an updated snippet:

```js
this.$navigateTo(LogIn, {
  frame: "app",
  clearHistory: false,
  animated: false
})
```